# Nested json to one row with pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

> {"name": "Sara", "grade": "1", "school": "Buckeye", "teacher": "Ms. Black", "sci": {"gr": "A", "perc": "93"}, "math": {"gr": "B+", "perc": "88"}, "eng": {"gr": "A-", "perc": "91"}}

I have the json file above (named test) and I am trying to turn it into a dataframe in python using pandas.  The pd.read_json(test.csv) command returns two lines 'gr' and 'perc' instead of one.  Is there a way to make one row and the nested columns be gr.sci, gr.math, gr.eng, perc.sci, perc.math, perc.eng?

Comment: how would that one line look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `pd.json_normalize()`, as follows:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(test)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   name grade   school    teacher sci.gr sci.perc math.gr math.perc eng.gr eng.perc
0  Sara     1  Buckeye  Ms. Black      A       93      B+        88     A-       91
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.json_normalize` after convert json file to python data structure:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = json.load('data.json')
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

```
>>> df
   name grade   school    teacher sci.gr sci.perc math.gr math.perc eng.gr eng.perc
0  Sara     1  Buckeye  Ms. Black      A       93      B+        88     A-       91
```